# Freeswitch: How to determine if call was answered when bridging an inbound and outbound call?

Tags: python, freeswitch

In this implementation, I'm trying to do call patching between an inbound call and a outbound call via the `session.bridge()` command.

I have already received the inbound call and my Python script is playing. In this script I'm trying to patch the running call with the numbers in the `number_list(list of numbers)` one by one until the list is exhausted or till the call is patched and answered.

My Code:

```
for cp_num in connObj.cp_list:
    ivr_log.debug("Attempting to dial Call Patch Number:%s"%(cp_num['cp_no']))
    connObj.patch_uuid = uuid.uuid1()
    cmd_str = """{ignore_early_media=true,execute_on_answer=record_session %s/%s_%s.wav,origination_uuid=%s,originate_timeout=45,script_name=gaadi_test}freetdm/wp4/a/%s"""%(connObj.recording_path,connObj.uuid,connObj.caller_id,connObj.patch_uuid,cp_num['cp_no'])
    connObj.bridge(cmd_str) #BRIDGE
    connObj.hangup_cause = connObj.getVar("last_bridge_hangup_cause")
    if connObj.hangup_cause in ['NORMAL_CLEARING', '']:
        connObj.cp_status = "SUCCESS"
        return True
connObj.cp_status = "FAILED"
connObj.playback(connObj.path_sound + 'all_reps_busy.wav')
return False
```

Multiple numbers to the bridge command for sequential dialing.
From freeswitch documentation:
Multiple endpoints sequential -- no limit to failover number

```
bridge <target_endpoint>[|<target_endpoint>]
```

My Implementation

```
cmd1 = """{ignore_early_media=true,originate_timeout=45}[origination_uuid=%s,script_name=gaadi_test]freetdm/wp4/a/%s"""%(connObj.patch_uuid1,connObj.cp_list[0]['cp_no'])
cmd2 = """[origination_uuid=%s,script_name=gaadi_test]freetdm/wp4/a/%s"""%(connObj.patch_uuid2,connObj.cp_list[1]['cp_no'])
cmd = "%s[|%s]"%(cmd3,cmd4)
ivr_log.debug("CMD=%s"%(cmd))
connObj.call_patch_start_time = int(time.time())
connObj.patch_start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
connObj.bridge(cmd)
```

P.S.: ConnObj.bridge(cmd) is working perfect for only one target point.

Sequential Dialing solution:
just a little changes in cmd1 and cmd2. I have not confirmed if the origination uuid will be different for both the calls.

```
cmd1 = """{ignore_early_media=true,originate_timeout=45,script_name=gaadi_test}[origination_uuid=%s]freetdm/wp4/a/%s"""%(connObj.patch_uuid1,connObj.cp_list[0]['cp_no'])
cmd2 = """[origination_uuid=%s]freetdm/wp4/a/%s"""%(connObj.patch_uuid2,connObj.cp_list[1]['cp_no'])
cmd="%s|%s" #removed the brackets and its working now.
connObj.bridge(cmd)
```

EDIT:

Finally I solved the problem with Stanislav's approach. I used api_on_answer. On answer I wrote a file on the disk and then checked whether the file was present or not. If the file was present then the call was answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `execute_on_answer` variable to execute a hangup:

https://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Variable_execute_on_answer

But in general, `mod_python` is not the right place for such tasks: the script is executed as a thread inside FreeSWITCH process, and you don;t have any control while a freeSWITCH application is being executed (bridge in your case). A much better option is to use the event socket library (ESL), and then you can control the call flow asynchronously and receive events that are relevant to call state changes.

Comment: I'm using ESL. I have three python files. ESL.py in which i'm importing _ESL as import _ESL. ivrlib.py in which i'm importing ESL.py as from ESL.py import * and then i'm import ivrlib.py in my ivr.py as import ivrlib. I'm adding the exact code in the question above. Please have a look.

Comment: The other thing I was trying was to pass n arguments to the freeswitch in bridge command for sequential dialing, which is just have the solution in my case, since I wont get all the details of the answered call in my script but it still solves one problem of breaking in between when the list is not over yet. According to documentation, the code should work, but its not working. I am adding that code in the question above.

Comment: which is just *half the solution

Comment: Ok. The sequential dialing is working now, so half the problem is solved. But how can I know which number answered the call? I'm Posting the solution to sequential dialing in the question.

Comment: Sequential bridging will solve one problem that I was facing. That is, when you call some numbers, the hangup cause generated is -ERR NORMAL_CLEARING when the user rejects the call. Which will terminate my loop, as I will get only NORMAL_CLEARING in the hangup cause, signifying that the call was answered, but the fact is it was not answered but rejected.

Comment: This one is important. I'll ask it here, and I'm opening a new question as well. How can I subscribe to  the event CHANNEL_ANSWER in my IVR.py script. is it possible? Can I make my program enter a while loop till the event arrives?? "event plain CHANNEL_ANSWER"